# C# And OleDbException

Tags: c#, database

Today i got that error:

> "No value given for one or more required parameters."

i'm making this program like 1 month but i hadn't error like that, i don't know what does it mean. can u help? here is code:

P.S school_DatabaseDataSet has table named Classes.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    classesTableAdapter1.Fill(school_DatabaseDataSet.Classes);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = school_DatabaseDataSet.Classes;
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `SelectCommand` of `classesTableAdapter1`?

Comment: classesTableAdapter1 have some sql associated with it and the error actually caused by this sql. Could you please provide us how it's setted up?

Comment: if the code hasn't changed; that leaves the data. I wonder if you are now sending a `null` as one of the values; `null` values *are not sent* as command parameters - they need to be `DBNull.Value` to be sent as database nulls.

Comment: Guys i have one more problem, i've cleared event log (Cuz it was full) so now i'm getting error like that [see image](http://s020.radikal.ru/i702/1303/d7/5681538fef47.jpg)

Comment: @user2132375 that *looks* to be completely unrelated...

Answer (score 0):

if `school_DatabaseDataSet` is a Dataset and `Classes` is the table of it, then

```
classesTableAdapter1.Fill(school_DatabaseDataSet.Tables["Classes"]);
dataGridView1.DataSource  =school_DatabaseDataSet.Tables["Classes"];
```